# How can I crawl images loaded in canvas using JavaScript on a website using python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, canvas

I want to crawl this musictheory.net [websites](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/10). I first tried using requests and BeautifulSoup it did not work. I was able to finally use hellium and BeautifulSoup to crawl the text. When I tried to crawl the images, I did a research and I noticed the text are embedded in a button using `role="button"` , clicking any line of text usually activate different images which is usually displayed at the top of the webpage. When I inspect the webpage by right clicking on the webpage and clicking "inspect (Q)", I saw that there is no `<img src="".............>` what I noticed was there is `<canvas style="position"........etc....></canvas>` and it is inside this canvas that images are loaded in using JavaScript I guess. I was confused looking at the code in all the `<script .......xyz.js></script>`. I would be glad if anyone can help me solve this problem. Below is code that I used to print the canvas attribute.

```
from helium import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/10'
browser = start_chrome(url, headless=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

canvas_links = []

y = soup.select('script')

for canvas in y:
    canvas_links.append(canvas)

for can in canvas_links:
    print(can)
```

Comment: if `JavaScript` use `Canvas` then you will have to use `JavaScript` to get it.

Comment: Thank you @furas. I will do my research in that direction. You can also help me with any information link that can help.

Comment: I found only that it loads font with name `musictype-regular-webfont.woff` - maybe it uses it to display on canvas.